# Image hover until next text and make zoom icon center when responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

I create simple image hover and want only image that opacity. But this case, the text get hover.
How to make only image to hover and make zoom icon center when responsive use?
Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6U5Wd/

```
<div class='img-zoom'>
                        <a href='http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff' data-lightbox='1' data-title='222'>
                        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff' class='img-responsive img-thumbnail' alt='222'>
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in'></span></a>
                    </div>          
                    <p align='justify'>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.</p>
                    <ul type='square'>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text</li>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text</li>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text</li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Unsure of the solution, but the issue is in this line: "<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span>" can you give us css on those classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container holding both the image and `<span>` tag is your `<a>` tag, we need to make sure of two things:

1. The elements inside the `<a>` tag stay within the container, for this we use the `position: relative;`
2. The `<span>` is coming after the `<img>` but it should be over it on hover, so we add `float:left;` for it to stay over (this works because you have the `position: absolute` on your `<span>`)
3. Additionally, your text is likely to `float` left too because of our previous container, so I have added `clear:both` after every image. A little of your other properties like `width` and `top` changed too.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6U5Wd/13/)**

Comment: can we make zoom in icon location in center? because now, the zoom icon when mobile site, the location is not same with tab and desktop site?

Comment: @LenaQueen I tried this on iPhone 5 and it seems centered, could you show me a screenshot of how it looks on your device?

Comment: I have update on fiddle, the problem when image size 600px and show on mobile. http://jsfiddle.net/6U5Wd/10/ You can please drag size on fiddle to left. Icon will appear on top as usual and if smallest, the icon will appear on bottom

Comment: @LenaQueen Have a look at the updated fiddle, made a few changes, full screen result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6U5Wd/13/embedded/result/)

Comment: Sorry, I have test and clear my cache. And then the image will broken. This appear because .img-zoom a float left.... You can try that, any solution?

Comment: @LenaQueen What do you mean? Could you paste a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: I have update on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6U5Wd/14/embedded/result/..... Please clear cache/history first. I test on firefox and result : http://cdn.img42.com/c5545b88d66d22c09fb2c1bc5bb3e699.png

Comment: @LenaQueen I get now what you mean, they are not getting adjusted in smaller viewport and overlap, for this you can add the class `col-sm-12 col-xs-12` to your `<a>` that's holding the image and the icon. Have a look **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/k6KMJ/)**

Comment: Any solution with CSS only? I saw width image and width content not same http://cdn.img42.com/848e50e1a1d6ad6be082e88e267b2e3b.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52026/discussion-between-i-can-has-cheezburger-and-lena-queen)

Answer (score 0):

In the `img-zoom` class you need to contain the width and height of that effect. At the point you have it now it`s doing a 100% height and 95% width (you can notice that when you hover over it you have a 5% on the right that does not get the layer over it).

So you can go about it a couple of ways, like giving the width and the height of `img-zoom` to be the size of the image and the zoom icon. But this might break it for other resolutions and whatnot, so watch out for that.